# In Azure web app, wwwroot directroy size is increasing massively

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, dotnetnuke

In Azure web app, wwwroot directroy size is increasing massively. As I mentioned in \site\wwwroot\Install\Temp folder which stores the extension backup is carrying very large size. Is it safe to delete the files in temp folder, will it affect in anyway to my live website?
Please respond as soon as possible.
Thank you.
[image]

I want to free up some space on my site folder as it is getting way too large.

Comment: Yes,you can clear the temp folder.

Comment: `will it affect in anyway to my live website`, AFAIK,it will not affect any of the deployed files/folders.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is safe to remove items from this folder, however, it is very uncommon for this to happen.  Since that is a processing folder it shouldn't impact the usability of the site in any way.

I would suggest looking at why that isn't being cleaned up. Typically from failed installations/upgrades of modules or extensions.